# Xorg and KDE fail to start after upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, kde

I'm running Arch Linux on a Lenovo ThinkPad with integrated Intel GPU hardware. After my recent pacman update, KDE fails to start. The system ran fine before the update. There were no errors during the update and I did not force anything or do anything unusual.

The first and only error message in the xorg log is:

```
xf86OpenSerial: Cannot open device /dev/input/event17. Permission denied
```

I have sddm disabled currently. I boot up, log in, and type `startx`. KDE appears to start, but then the screen goes blank. Every few seconds, the desktop background will flash, but mostly the screen is blank and unresponsive to the mouse.

While this was happening I switched to virtual console 2, logged in and viewed the xorg log. The following photograph shows the error message (mentioned above). Grep indicates that there are no other error messages.

[image]

If I kill the GUI user session, switch back to vitual console 1 and run `startx` again, X will start but KDE does not start. At that point, my situation is exactly the same as described in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=227067) thread.

> My plasma desktop is not starting after the last update... It's giving
>   a black screen and a little graphical message at the top left screen
>   corner saying: **Could not sync environment to dbus**.

Here's a photo of my screen. It's plain old X.

[image]

The solution proposed there is to remove `~/.config`. I tried that and it did not resolve the problem or change anything.

As part of my troubleshooting, I tried adding my user to the input group (even though my other Arch KDE machines work without having done this), which is the group that owns files /dev/input/event*

```
sudo usermod -a -G input myuser
```

Now there are no errors shown in the xorg log, but KDE still fails to start and I get X with the dialog message: Could not sync environment to dbus.

Further searching led me to the following blog:

[X freezing as "systemd-logind: got pause for [...]"](https://chrisdown.name/2016/10/18/x-freezing-systemd-logind-got-pause.html)

However, I do not have two instances of dbus-daemon running. Just one.

The xorg log continues to show these messages:

```
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
(II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
(II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
(II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
(II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:75
(II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
(II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:81
```

The system is using xf86-input-evdev and xorg-xinput. My user's [.xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit) is standard and was created according to the Arch wiki and it hasn't changed recently.

## UPDATE

Next I removed ~/.cache as per mviereck's comment.

That did not resolve it. The error now is

```
xf86OpenConsole: Cannot Open /dev/tty0 (Permission Denied).
```

My user is a member of the tty group.

I also reinstalled xorg-server as per [this forum thread](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=38633) but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: You can try to remove ~/.cache, too.

Comment: @mviereck I tried that but still no luck. The error now is `xf86OpenConsole: Cannot Open /dev/tty0 (Permission Denied)`. My user is a member of the tty group. I also reinstalled xorg-server as per https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=38633 but that did not resolve it.

Comment: Try `startx -- vtN` with N being the tty number you are logged in. (vt1...vt6 as in tty1....tty6). Newer versions of Xorg have a more strict vt handling. Or try `startkde`, maybe it runs X / xinit better than startx.

Comment: With `startx -- vt1` I get the same X dialog error "Could not sync environment to dbus." When I run startx it calls startkde. If I call startkde directly, the $DISPLAY env var is not set (and probably others are not set either).

Comment: I'm about to commit the intolerable sin of re-installing Arch...

Comment: Does it start if you log in as root? (Another sin, I know ...). Earlier version of X start as setuid wrapper, newer don't (at least on debian). Before reinstalling arch, you could try to setuid Xorg.

Comment: If I run `startx` either as root or with sudo, X now runs without the usual error "Could not sync environment to dbus." However, KDE doesn't even try to launch which is strange because the last line of .xinitrc is `exec startkde`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea about setuid. I ran `sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/Xorg` but the problem remains: X launches instead of KDE and I get an X dialog error "Could not sync environment to dbus."

Comment: Just a try: `dbus-launch xinit ~/.xinitrc -- :1 vt1` or `dbus-launch startx`. I just tested with success on tty2: `dbus-launch xinit startkde -- :2 vt2`

Comment: @mviereck thank you again. I tried both commands. Now KDE launches but it gives a black screen. The mouse is visible and can move, but the black screen is unresponsive. The Xorg log shows no errors. However, I see the same "systemd-logind: got pause..." mentioned in my question.

Comment: I wanted to switch to BTRFS anyway, so I am reinstalling the entire system now. Before doing that I briefly tried Wayland / Weston. The basic Weston desktop would come up. Never did get Xorg & KDE working again tho...

Comment: I'm getting the same issue here - some additional info I've noticed is that the sddm user session is also failing to start, with the error message about XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not being set.